# Laravel Eloquent - Fetch summaries substring groupedBy and sum total field of group

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fetch a list from my database of all my Summaries with the according Sum of the total field. To visualize the table it would look similar to this:

```
ID. Code.       Total.      Created_at.         Updated_at
1   61B5A4C5    1437.64     2021-06-22 11:18:09 2021-06-22 11:18:09
2   A9B5311C    711.44      2021-06-22 11:19:10 2021-06-22 11:19:10
3   1426CDC5    711.44      2021-06-22 11:19:27 2021-06-22 11:19:27
4   8684A47A    1007.32     2021-06-22 11:31:54 2021-06-22 11:31:54
5   68B2C2AE    1238.10     2021-06-22 11:32:22 2021-06-22 11:32:22
6   D0D08082    864.33      2021-06-22 11:51:54 2021-06-22 11:51:54
7   1A448FC5    864.33      2021-06-22 11:53:38 2021-06-22 11:53:38
8   25DA8382    375.92      2021-06-22 11:54:41 2021-06-22 11:54:41
9   B81E41CA    711.44      2021-06-23 12:06:39 2021-06-23 12:06:39
10  A4302991    10233.64    2021-06-23 12:08:43 2021-06-23 12:08:43
```

The result I am trying to get will look similar to this:

```
Sum.    Created_at
5000.00 2021-06-22 
3999.00 2021-06-23
```

But how can I accomplish this using Eloquent? The created_at field is almost always random so I have to substring the value so it will always pick the first 10 letters, which would be `2021-06-22`. And the sum should be the sum of all the total fields within the group

**I tried**

```
Summary::groupBy(DB::raw('substr(created_at, 0, 9)'))
     ->selectRaw('*, sum(total) as sum')
     ->get());

Summary::groupBy('created_at')->sum('total')
```

**UPDATE**

The solution I was looking for is this, You indeed don't need substring for this query. The DATE function works perfectly fine.

```
DB::table('summaries')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('sum(total) as sum'))
            ->groupBy('date')->pluck('sum','date')
```

This returns the following result which is exactly what I was looking for!

```
"2021-06-22" => "1886.31"
"2021-06-23" => "2118.16"
```

For anyone with a similar issue, I hope this helps you out!

Comment: `created_at` is a `datetime`, not a `varchar`; don't use `substr`, use `date_format()`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp. Also, what does *"does not work"* mean? What is the result of your Query?

Comment: Oh, sidenote, in my test case, `substr(created_at, 0, 9)` returned `EMPTY`, but `substr(created_at, 1, 10)` returned `2021-01-01`. I'd still recommend `date_format()`, but you can use `substr()`, but `start` (2nd param) cannot be `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```php
Summary::groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
        ->selectRaw('DATE(created_at) `date`, sum(total) `sum`')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for the data manipulation you can use,
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

I think substr for that is not correct way, because of as Tim mentioned its not a string